# Why Isn't This Function Called "Left"?

Tags: elixir

Ok, I really feel dumb for having to ask this but I’m very curious.

In Jose’s 2023 keynote he showed this example of why the new type implementation won’t prevent certain bugs:

```
def left and right do
  Enum.random([left, right])
end
```

So just to see if he was just making something up to make his point I tried it in `iex` and sure enough–there’s an `and` function. What puzzles me is how is it that `left` isn’t the name of the function? How is it possible to have arguments before and after the name of the function?

Comment: The first parameter to `def` is basically a prototype call to the function.  For a usual user-defined function, this would look like `f(x)` - but for defining an operator, it would look like the normal application of that operator.  So `def a + b` would redefine addition - probably not a good idea!  What you have here is basically the same thing, since `and` is parsed as an operator keyword.

Comment: @jasonharper `Kernel.def/2` is a macro and therefore it receives everything as a single argument (which is _AST_.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), everything is a macro. [`Kernel.def/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.15.5/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L5118) is no exception. Macros receive *AST* of its params rather than params themselves. This is what actually receives `Kernel.def/2` (I simplified the block for the sake of clarity)

```elixir
iex||1 ▶ quote do
...||1 ▶   left and right do
...||1 ▶     :ok
...||1 ▶   end
...||1 ▶ end
{:and, [context: Elixir, imports: [{2, M}]],
 [{:left, [], Elixir}, {:right, [], [[do: :ok]]}]}
```

That said, this is the duty of `Kernel.def/2` macro to feature [infix “operators”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir).

For the further reference, one should dig into [`:elixir_def`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.15.5/lib/elixir/src/elixir_def.erl#L198) codebase.